# Do I need 2 separate applications in Node.js, one for visitors and one for CRUD admins?

Tags: node.js, web-applications, nginx, express, varnish

#### Intro

I'm trying out Node.js right now ( coming from PHP background).

I'm already catching the ***vibe*** of the workflow with it (events, promises, inheritance..*haven't figured out streams yet*).

I've chosen a graphic portfolio web app as my first nodejs project. I know node.js might not fit best for this use case but I it's a good playground and I need to do this anyway.

The concept:

1. The visitors will only browse through pretty pictures in albums, no
   logging in or subscirptions, nothing.
2. The administrators will add,modify, reorder.. CRUD the photo
   albums. So I need there Auth, ACL, Validation, imagemagick... a lot
   more than just on the frontend.

Currently I'm running one instance of Node.js, so both admin and visitor code is in one shared codebase and shared node memory runtime, which to me looks unnecessary performance-wise.

---

## Question

*For both performance and usability:*

Should I **continue running one instance** of node for both admin and visitor areas of the web app or should I run them as **2 separate instances**? (or subtasks? - honestly i haven't worked with subtasks/child processes)

---

#### Ideas floating around

- Use nginx as proxy if splitting into 2 applications
- Look into https://stackoverflow.com/a/5683938/339872. There's some interesting
  mentions of tools to help manage processes.

Comment: Since you are just trying out node, I would just keep it as one application and wait until you have a (rooted in reality) reason to split it. See http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Answer (score 0):

I would setup admin.mysite.com and have that hosted on another server...or use nginx to proxy requests from that domain to your admin.js node app.